# Is there any relation Trace and Boundary?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I understand the trace is sum of diagonal elements of a matrix. Further the boundary I always perceive as a 'end points' of bounded domain. However on the link below:

http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/frey/cours/UdC/ma691/ma691_ch2.pdf

On section 2.2.4 The trace of a function is defined:  ".. the trace of the function on the boundary of the domain"

My Question is what is the meaning of trace here; compare to sum of diagonals? Is this trace means something else?

Comment: Not really, I suppose. We may interprete "trace" as meaning something like "footprint", in the the linked pdf th e"footprint" the function leaves on the boundary, and for matrices just meaning as much as "a characteristic property"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen May I ask please, if this operator is required to define the norm appropriately for multidimensional Sobolev space. In other words for one dimensional case this operator is not necessary?